# Free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: homological-algebra, free-modules

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and consider $M = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as an $R$-module. In my course notes, we have constructed a free resolution of $M$ that has infinite length:

\begin{equation}
... \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} 
\end{equation}
and now they state that any free resolution of $M$ as an $R$-module has infinite length. However, I have no idea how I could prove this.

Comment: If there was a resolution with finite length, its Ext groups would vanish in high enough degree. But calcuating Ext with the above resolution gives non-zero Ext in arbitrarily high degree. As Ext group are independent (canonically isomorphic) of the resolution, no free resolution can have finite length. That's my guess, atleast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ThePuix explained, the simplest idea is to use some derived functor constructed from this resolution, as it will not depend on the choice of resolution.

Explicitly, if $F$ is a right exact functor on the category of $R$-modules, and 
$$\dots \to P_2\to P_1\to P_0\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
is a projective resolution of $R$-module (in particular, it can be a free resolution), then the homology of the complex
$$ \dots\to F(P_2)\to F(P_1)\to F(P_0)\to 0$$
does not depend on the choice of resolution (up to a canonical isomorphism), and the homology group at $F(P_n)$ is by definition the $n$th derived functor $L_nF(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

If there was a finite length resolution (say of length $d$) then obviously we would have $L_nF(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for any $F$ and for every $n>d$.

But we can give a counter-example: let us choose for instance $F(X)=X\otimes_R A$ for some $R$-module $A$. The derived functors are then by definition $Tor_n^R(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},A)$. Using your free resolution, we easily see that $Tor_n^R(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},A)$ is given by the homology of the complex
$$ \dots\to A\xrightarrow{\cdot 2} A\xrightarrow{\cdot 2} A\to 0$$
so $Tor_n^R(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},A)= A[2]/2A$ where $A[2]$ is the $2$-torsion subgroup of $A$.

If we take $A=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then $Tor_n^R(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\neq 0$, which concludes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for simplicity. There is a non-split exact sequence $0\to M\to R\to M\to 0$, so by dimension shifting we have, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\operatorname{Ext}_R^{n+1}(M,M)\cong\operatorname{Ext}_R^n(M,M)
$$

On the other hand, a finite free resolution would imply that $\operatorname{Ext}_R^k(M,M)$ vanishes for sufficiently high $k$. This would imply that $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M,M)$ vanishes, which it doesn't because the given exact sequence is not split.